# Regenerate the installation certificate

Tags: ejabberd

I changed the hostname of my ejabberd server. How do I regenerate a new certificate for the new hostname? Would it be easier to save the ejabberd.yml file and reinstall ejabberd with the new hostname?
Thanks

I'm still gathering some info before running

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the self-signed certificate generated by the ejabberd installers during the installation? You can see the call to `openssl` to generate it in the source code, and generate it yourself. See [make-packages line 94](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/706424f0d24a5abe08e3238eb9e537f724ce3074/tools/make-packages#L94).

On the other hand, if you use a FQDN and setup as required, you can let ejabberd use ACME to obtain the certificates itself, see [ACME documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/basic/#acme).